# Android going "back" to previous fragment event

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app setup that uses fragments in various place, in one case a fragment exists and upon pressing a button another replaces it using replace() all normal so far, however when the user presses the android back button and the new fragment is removed/popped (whatever the system uses) and the app returns to the first fragment there is no event being fired that i can override to perform an action.

is this normal?, the docs seem to suggest that onResume should be fired in this instance, other sites don't, and my app doesn't, if anyone has any clue if this is normal behaviour or not that be great and if it is what event can i hook into?

Edit: i forgot that all of this is occuring as nested fragments, the first fragment is the child of another so is added using a child fragment manager the second replaces the first using its regular fragment manager, besides the issue im describing this is working great

how the first fragment is originally put in place

```
        Menu_Fragment menufragment = new Menu_Fragment();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_container, menufragment, "_menu_fragment").commit();
```

How the second fragment is "added"

```
                    Google_Map_Container_Fragment mapcontainerfrag = new Google_Map_Container_Fragment();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_container, mapcontainerfrag, "addedmap").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: Are you retaining the fragment? maybe show some code?

Comment: It should call onResume. Have you checked that correctly ? I mean how can you say it is not fired ? By the way you usually put the code that need to be executed either on popback or screenrotation in the onActivityCreated method.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the fragment ?

Comment: @user1281750 : im not explicitly retaining the fragment anywhere and i believe it doesnt happen automatically.

Comment: @HpTerm Im testing this by overriding pretty much all the methods at this stage and having Logs in place, plus the actual code i want to run if the methods were fired, also onActivityCreated is not called either

code has been added, its really simple and straight up though

Comment: @fury-s12 can you paste the code fragment/activity where you override all these methods.